# EF SQL WHERE using LOWER() conversion for string comparison

Tags: entity-framework, query-performance

My application is using Entity Framework over a SQL Azure Database.

It has a feature that allows the the user to search for records based on a given phone number. The table being searched has many columns, including 3 columns for phone numbers: a `BusinessPhone`, a `HomePhone` and a `CellPhone` column.  All three of these columns are indexed.

My EF DbContext is generating the following as part of the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE (10 = [Extent1].[Debtor_DebtorStatus]) AND 
(((LOWER([Extent1].[BusinessPhone])) = (LOWER(N'012345678'))) 
OR ((LOWER([Extent1].[HomePhone])) = (LOWER(N'012345678'))) 
OR ((LOWER([Extent1].[CellPhone])) = (LOWER(N'012348678'))) 
)
```

The query is taking about 3 minutes to return a response (even when I run it in SQL Management Studio).

If I edit this SQL statement and remove the `LOWER()` function, then it executes in less than a second!!!

Is there some setting I can flick to make EntityFramework NOT use the `LOWER()` function in the generated SQL statement?

Of if that is not possible, is there a way I can intercept this SQL statement and remove the `LOWER()` functions in code before execution on the database?

Comment: What about changing the datatype of phone columns?

Comment: To what though?